# VPN doesn't work when I connect to my router via Repeater

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, vpn, repeater

I have a [FritzRepeater 1750E](https://en.avm.de/products/fritzwlan/fritzwlan-repeater-1750e/) that is connected to my router, a UPC Router EVW3226. For home-office I need to connect to my work Barracuda VPN. This works fine when connected directly to my rounter, however when I am connected to the repeater, the connection drops with timeout error messages.

Just confirmed that the repeater is NOT set to do a double NAT, the gateway IP of the router is `192.168.0.1`, the repeater's ip is `192.168.0.2` and the devices IP and registerd gatway IP stays the same when I switch Wifi hosts at `192.168.0.11` and `192.168.0.1` respectively.

As far as I am aware, the repeater should work on layer2 and the vpn on layer3 so I am confused as to where to start debugging and what settings might be responsible for this behaviour. Any ideas how to get the vpn working with the repeater?

Answer (score 0):

Did you connect the repeater as a double NAT?  That stops many VPN clients from connecting. If the VPN Client can be set for NAT Traversal, try that. Also see if remote end (Barracuda VPN) can be set for NAT Traversal.

Try a different router (not a Repeater) and set up the router as you need on the same subnet as your main network.  That may be a better approach.

Comment: Just checked it, no double nat(I am pretty sure, according to settings and ip config). See my updated post.

Comment: Still try a different router. The repeater you used may have blocked VPN.  I use VPN a lot and numerous things can block the VPN you use.